# native ruby methods for compressing/encrypt strings?

Tags: ruby, encryption, compression

Hi is there any native function (not install other gem, or not calling openssl from shell) to compress string or encrypt a string?

sort of like mysql compress.

`"a very long and loose string".compress 

output = "8d20\1l\201"`

`"8d20\1l\201".decompress

output = "a very long and loose string"?`

and likewise to encrypt some string?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/classes/Zlib.html

```
  # aka compress
  def deflate(string, level)
    z = Zlib::Deflate.new(level)
    dst = z.deflate(string, Zlib::FINISH)
    z.close
    dst
  end

  # aka decompress
  def inflate(string)
    zstream = Zlib::Inflate.new
    buf = zstream.inflate(string)
    zstream.finish
    zstream.close
    buf
  end
```

Encryption from http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/991

```
require 'openssl'
require 'digest/sha1'
c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
c.encrypt
# your pass is what is used to encrypt/decrypt
c.key = key = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest("yourpass")
c.iv = iv = c.random_iv
e = c.update("crypt this")
e << c.final
puts "encrypted: #{e}\n"
c = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new("aes-256-cbc")
c.decrypt
c.key = key
c.iv = iv
d = c.update(e)
d << c.final
puts "decrypted: #{d}\n"
```

Comment: According to the Zlib docs, `Zlib::Deflate.deflate(string[, level])` and `Zlib::Inflate.inflate(string[, level])` are "almost equivalent" to the above deflate/inflate methods.

Answer (score 5):

[OpenSSL](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/index.html) and [Zlib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/zlib/rdoc/index.html). There’s an example of OpenSSL usage in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128939/simple-encryption-in-ruby-without-external-gems).

Comment: Not that you really imply any order of operation but one gets better compression rate if the text is first compressed and then encrypted.

Comment: You should get virtually no compression if the file is first encrypted.  Read this:  https://blog.appcanary.com/2016/encrypt-or-compress.html