# Device token_authenticatable is not working with encrypted auth_tokens

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encryption, devise, devise-token-auth

We have recently encrypted all our auth_tokens in the users table. I have modified the `authenticate_user_from_token!` in ApplicationController to `encrypt` the params[:auth_token] before comparing in database. It fetches the user record and `sign_in user, store: false` creates an entry in `sessions` table.

```
def authenticate_user_from_token!
  user_token = encrypt(params[:auth_token].presence)
  user = user_token && User.find_by_authentication_token(user_token)
  if user
    sign_in user, store: false
  end
end
```

However, it doesn't actually log the user in. It takes me to the login page. Is `Devise` using the `auth_token` somewhere else where I need to encrypt it or am I missing something else?

Comment: What is the console output when you try to log in?

Comment: shouldn't this be `encrypt(params[:auth_token])`?

Comment: Khaled, yes it should be `encrypt(params[:auth_token])`, it was a typo. I have corrected it in question.

Comment: Maybe you should check devise `sessions_controller`